# DataClassJsonMixin.from_dict leaves nested dict as a dict

Tags: python, python-dataclasses

In file `nested.py` I have

```
import typing as t

from dataclasses import dataclass
from dataclasses_json import DataClassJsonMixin


@dataclass
class B(DataClassJsonMixin):
    b_val: int


@dataclass
class A(DataClassJsonMixin):
    val: t.Union[str, B]
```

Now if I run this script

```
import nested

a = nested.A(nested.B(42))
print(f"a.val {a.val} has type {type(a.val)}")
d = a.to_dict()
print(f"d is {d}") 
new_a = nested.A.from_dict(d)
print(f"new_a.val {new_a.val} has type {type(new_a.val)}")
```

I get

`a.val B(b_val=42) has type <class 'nested.B'>`

`d is {'val': {'b_val': 42}}`

`new_a.val {'b_val': 42} has type <class 'dict'>`

I took a look at `dataclasses-json` and seems to be giving up [here](https://github.com/lidatong/dataclasses-json/blob/3dc59e01ccdfec619ee4e4c3502b9759b67c3fa8/dataclasses_json/core.py#L278).

Can we not have unions of non-primitive types in `DataClassJsonMixin`?

Comment: I didn't use `dataclasses_json` yet, but seeing the behavior isn't too surprising. Type annotations are non-binding in python after all, it's just for documentation and static type checkers like `mypy`.
The only similar library that I know that actually asserts that type annotations are enforced at runtime is `pydantic`. Would it help you to see this snipped translated into using that library, or are you committed to `dataclasses_json`?

Comment: @Arne.         Thanks, I understand that type annotations are generally not considered at runtime, but if you look at the link you'll see that the module uses them to reconstruct the objects.  And yes, I'm bound to using `dataclasses_json` currently.

Comment: ah, so it works if the type is just `B` instead of `t.Union[str, B]`? You might get a better answer on the project's issue tracker then, they should be able to tell you whether it's a bug, planned to be supported, or unsupportable.

Comment: @Arne.  Done.  I debated whether that was or not asking here was also appropriate, but this question seemed to fall w/in the criterion of "software tools commonly used by programmers" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) given the popularity of the project.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will suit you:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass, asdict
from typing import Union

from validated_dc import ValidatedDC


@dataclass
class B(ValidatedDC):
    val: int


@dataclass
class A(ValidatedDC):
    val: Union[str, B]


data = {"val": "s"}
a = A(**data)
assert a.val == "s"
assert not a.get_errors()

data = {"val": {"val": 1}}
a = A(**data)
assert a.val == B(1)
assert a.val.val == 1
assert asdict(a) == {"val": {"val": 1}}
assert not a.get_errors()
```

ValidatedDC: https://github.com/EvgeniyBurdin/validated_dc

Comment: Thanks much, unfortunately I don't have that much control over changing the existing codebase.

Found this workaround in the meantime:

`from dataclasses_json import cfg`
`cfg.global_config.decoders[t.Union[str, B]] = <custom decoder function>`